# nginx and owncloud in subfolder

Tags: php, nginx, owncloud

I want to have a owncloud instance in a subfolder on my nginx server. But I have problems with some of the files requested by opwncloud (it seems css and js don't load).

Here is the nginx conf file for this virtual host :

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    blackblock.22decembre.eu;
   return 301     https://blackblock.22decembre.eu$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 default_server ssl;

server_name blackblock.22decembre.eu;
root /srv/www/blackblock/;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/blackblock.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/blackblock.errors.log;

index index.html index.php;

# This block will catch static file requests, such as images, css, js
# The : prefix is a "non-capturing" mark, meaning we do not require
# the pattern to be captured into $1 which should help improve performance
location ~* \.(:ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|png)$ {
    # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

# remove the robots line if you want to use wordpress" virtual robots.txt
# location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# this prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

#location ~ ^(?<script_name>.+?\.php)(?<path_info>/.*)?$ {
location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /roundcube/program/js/tiny_mce/ { alias /usr/share/tinymce/www/; }
location /roundcube/(config|temp|logs) { deny all;}

 ##### owncloud
 location ~ /owncloud/ {
root /srv/www/blackblock/owncloud/;
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;

#client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
    #fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

    location ~ ^/remote.php(/.*)$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
            deny all;
    }

# The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;
rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;
rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

    # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    #location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
     #       expires 30d;
            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
      #      access_log off;
#   }
}

    ##### torrent (not related to owncloud, flask application)
location = /flask-torrent { rewrite ^ /flask-torrent/ last; }

 }
```

I can't find why owncloud doesn't load correctly !
You can have a look at the website, I feel fine and secured for that : https://blackblock.22decembre.eu/owncloud/ (cacert certificates).
If I launch a specific virtual host for owncloud, it works perfectly, but I don't want, I prefer it in a subfolder of this host (blackblock) !

Answer (score 2):

The reason why ownCloud doesn't work in a subfolder with nginx is that nginx, by default, doesn't include the subfolder in the parameter `SCRIPT_NAME`. If ownCloud is at `domain.tld/owncloud/index.php`, it expects `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to be `/owncloud/index.php`, but nginx by default (if you `include fastcgi_params;`) sets it to `index.php`. The solution is to override the behaviour: add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /owncloud/$fastcgi_script_name;` to the php-location-block in the nginx conf file.

Relevant parts of my nginx configuration file follow. Please note that I haven't tested it completely; on the first look it seems to work though. My System: nginx 1.2.1 and php 5.4.4 on Debian Wheezy 64 bit.

```
    location /owncloud/ {
            alias /var/www/owncloud/;
            location ~ ^/owncloud/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
                    deny all;
            }
            rewrite ^/owncloud/caldav(.*)$ /owncloud/remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
            rewrite ^/owncloud/carddav(.*)$ /owncloud/remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
            rewrite ^/owncloud/webdav(.*)$ /owncloud/remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;
            rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/host-meta /owncloud/public.php?service=host-meta last;
            rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/host-meta.json /owncloud/public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

            rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/carddav /owncloud/remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
            rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/caldav /owncloud/remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

            rewrite ^/owncloud/apps/([^/]*)/(.*\.(css|php))$ /owncloud/index.php?app=$1&getfile=$2 last;
            rewrite ^(/owncloud/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;

            location ~ ^/owncloud/(.+?\.php)/? {  # note the question mark here and in the next line!
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^/owncloud/(.+?\.php)(/?.*)$;
                    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;  # workaround for bug: try_files resets fastcgi_path_info for some reason.
                    try_files $fastcgi_script_name = 404;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
                    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /owncloud/$fastcgi_script_name;  # !!!
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me, I finally got a working solution from this blog:
http://www.aelog.org/install-owncloud-in-a-subdirectory-using-nginx/

Here's a version:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/cloud.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/cloud.example.com.key;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

    # Path to the root of your website (one level above owncloud folder)
    root /var/www;
    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
    gzip off;

    # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
    # This module is currently not supported.
    #pagespeed off;

    # ownCloud blacklist
    location ~ ^/owncloud/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README) {
        deny all;
        error_page 403 = /owncloud/core/templates/403.php;
    }

    index index.php;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README){
        deny all;
    }

    location /owncloud {
        error_page 403 = /owncloud/core/templates/403.php;
        error_page 404 = /owncloud/core/templates/404.php;

        rewrite ^/owncloud/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/owncloud/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/owncloud/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

        rewrite ^(/owncloud/core/doc[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

        # The following rules are only needed with webfinger
        rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;
        rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/owncloud/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
         root /var/www/html/;
         index index.html;
    }

    # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

I've created a documentation pull request here:
https://github.com/owncloud/documentation/pull/1704

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if you have reviewed this already but there are a few items including multiple Nginx location directives that are absent from the config you posted. I would recommend looking at the configuration notes (link at the bottom of this post) and ensuring that you have Nginx location directives for ownCloud and ownCloud data.

**Check the Nginx PHP handler:**

Your Nginx configuration should include a handler for PHP5-FPM, put this before the server directive at the top of the Nginx configuration:

```
upstream php5-fpm-handler {
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

**Check the Nginx directives:**

Examples:

```
location /owncloud {
   rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
   }

   location ~ ^/owncloud/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
         deny all;
   }
```

**Check the PHP5-FPM configuration:**

Also, please ensure that you PHP5-FPM pool configuration (usually somewhere like /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf on Ubuntu) is set to listen on the socket and not a TCP port which should match your handler. The configuration directives for PHP5-FPM socket versus port follow.

Example socket:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Example port (commented out to match the upstream handler):

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Also, if you have not already done so, please take a look at the ownCloud configuration notes for Nginx.

http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_others.html

Comment: the upstream, I didn't know about it ! I will try.

I can also tell you that the php5-fpm, pool and socket are well established and working, cause I have two other websites running php on seperate virtual hosts, and two (at least) other php services running in seperate folders of this precise virtual host.

Thanks.

Comment: I continue to have much problems. I can't load the css or js files.

Answer (score 0):

First let me point out that `/` isn't working yet `/index.php` is working, which means that the `index` statement for some reason isn't working, or that your URI is matching another block.

To be safe rewrite `location ~ /owncloud/` to `location ^~ /owncloud`

Your config needs a lot of rewriting, mind that the default configuration was made for owncloud installed on root directory, yours in a subdirecotry you need to fix few things, like keep in mind that `$uri` would include `/owncloud` and `/file.ext` would hop outside the owncloud folder, so all rewrites that are like

```
rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
```

need to be fixed because of 2 things,

1. `^/caldav(.*)$` will never happen, uri will always begin with `^/owncloud`
2. `/remote.php/...` will look outside owncloud

A fix would be something like this:

```
rewrite ^/owncloud/caldav(.*)$ /owncloud/remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
```

Try those for a start and tell me how it goes.

Comment: That helped a bit, but still don't have css or js files.

now, at least, the index works fine !